# VIM python filetype specific indent fails after 50 lines of one list

Tags: python, list, vim, indentation, auto-indent

I'm currently working on reformatting a python project to follow the 4 spaces indent style.  The project is being done in VIM with the following plugins: fugitive, snipmate, surround, git, supertab, minibufexpl, command-t. pyflakes-pathogen, ack, gundo, pydoc, pep8, py.test, makegreen, tasklist, nerdtree, ropevim .

My .vimrc is currently:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

let mapleader=","

filetype off

call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()


set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99

map <leader>td <Plug>TaskList
map <leader>g :GundoToggle<CR>

syntax on
filetype on
filetype plugin indent on

let g:pyflakes_use_quickfix = 0

let g:pep8_map='<leader>8'

au FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"

set completeopt=menuone,longest,preview
```

The project is not mine, and I would like to keep the code functionally untouched from the original.

The code consists of a few assignment operations.  The left side of each is the variable name, the right side is a very, very long list with multiple nested lists.

If I attempted to utilize VIM's re-indent functionality "gg=G" or even "100==" from the start of the asignment, VIM will properly indent the first fifty lines of the right side of the asignment.  However after the fiftieth line of the right side, VIM begins indenting the second level an additional four spaces.

```
animations = [
        ["stand", 0, amf_client_prediction,
            #   [3.0, "myanim", 0, 50, arf_cyclic|arf_loop_pos_0_25],
            [3.0, "anim_human", 50, 52, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25],
            [3.0, "anim_human", 60, 62, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.75],
            [3.0, "anim_human", 70, 72, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25],
            [3.0, "anim_human", 80, 82, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic|arf_two_handed_blade, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.5],
            ##   [35.0, "stand_woman", 0, 1059, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic|arf_two_handed_blade, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.5],
            ##   [43.0, "stand_woman_public", 0, 1313, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic|arf_two_handed_blade, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.5],
            #  [35.0, "tavern_stand", 0, 472, arf_cyclic|arf_loop_pos_0_25],
            ],
        ["stand_man", 0, amf_client_prediction,
            [11.0, "stand_man", 0, 315, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25],
            ],
        ["stand_player_first_person", 0, amf_client_prediction,
            [3.5, "anim_human", 90, 100, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25],
            [3.5, "anim_human", 110, 120, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25],
            ],
        ["jump", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_priority_jump|amf_play|amf_client_prediction|amf_continue_to_next,
            ##   [1.09, "jump", 22, 48, arf_blend_in_1],
            [1.0, "jump", 22, 46, arf_blend_in_1],
            ##   [0.8, "anim_human", 270, 272, arf_blend_in_4],
            ],
        ["jump_loop", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_priority_jump|amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
            ##   [0.8, "jump_loop", 0, 30, arf_blend_in_2|arf_cyclic],
            [0.5, "jump_loop", 0, 14, arf_blend_in_3|arf_cyclic],
            ],
        ["jump_end", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_priority_jump_end|amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
            ##   [0.1, "jump", 48, 55, arf_blend_in_1],
            [0.3, "jump", 48, 55, arf_blend_in_2],
            ],
        ["jump_end_hard", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_priority_jump_end|amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
            ##   [0.8, "jump_end_hard", 29, 54, arf_blend_in_1],
            [0.6, "jump_end_hard", 36, 54, arf_blend_in_1],
            ],
        ["stand_unarmed", 0, amf_client_prediction,
            [8, "noweapon_cstance", 0, 100, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25],
            ],
        ["stand_single", 0, amf_client_prediction,
            [9.0, "sword_loop01", 0, 200, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25],
            ],
        ["stand_greatsword", 0, amf_client_prediction,
            [6.0, "greatsword_cstance", 0, 91, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25],  
            ],
        ["stand_staff", 0, amf_client_prediction,
            [2.0, "staff_cstance", 0, 60, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.0],  
            ],
        ["stand_crossbow", 0, amf_client_prediction,
            [2.0, "staff_cstance", 0, 60, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.0],  
            ],
        ["turn_right", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
                [0.95, "stand_man", 0, 30, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25], #TODO
                ],
        ["turn_left", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
                [0.95, "stand_man", 0, 30, arf_use_stand_progress|arf_cyclic, 0, (0, 0, 0), 0.25], #TODO
                ],
        ["turn_right_single", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
                [0.95, "turn_man_onehanded", 0, 23, arf_cyclic|blend_in_walk|arf_make_walk_sound,pack2f(0.4,0.9), (0, 0, 0), 0.0],
                ],
        ["turn_left_single", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
                [0.95, "turn_man_onehanded", 30, 53, arf_cyclic|blend_in_walk|arf_make_walk_sound,pack2f(0.4,0.9), (0, 0, 0), 0.0],
                ],
        ["turn_right_staff", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
                [0.95, "turn_man_staff", 0, 20, arf_cyclic|blend_in_walk|arf_make_walk_sound,pack2f(0.4,0.9), (0, 0, 0), 0.0],
                ],
        ["turn_left_staff", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
                [0.95, "turn_man_staff", 30, 50, arf_cyclic|blend_in_walk|arf_make_walk_sound,pack2f(0.4,0.9), (0, 0, 0), 0.0],
                ],
        ["turn_right_greatsword", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
                [0.95, "turn_man_greatsword", 0, 20, arf_cyclic|blend_in_walk|arf_make_walk_sound,pack2f(0.4,0.9), (0, 0, 0), 0.0],
                ],
        ["turn_left_greatsword", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_play|amf_client_prediction,
                [0.95, "turn_man_greatsword", 30, 50, arf_cyclic|blend_in_walk|arf_make_walk_sound,pack2f(0.4,0.9), (0, 0, 0), 0.0],
                ],
        ["prepare_kick_0", acf_enforce_lowerbody, amf_priority_kick|amf_play|amf_client_prediction|amf_continue_to_next,
                [0.05, "kick_rightleg", 10, 12, arf_blend_in_3],
                ],
```

Does VIM utilize some sort of a buffer that sets a maximum number of lines that will be tracked for indentations?  If so, is there any way to increase this buffer size?

Otherwise, if this is simply a fault of the built-in indentation logic, do more robust third-party solutions exists that can provide indentation functionality for such a specific case?

If more information is necessary, I will update.

Answer (score 4):

hmmm in $VIMRUNTIME/indent/python.vim it looks like it scans back the past 50 lines to get context

```
let s:maxoff = 50        " maximum number of lines to look backwards for ()
```

you can see what VIM is using to indent by checking the indentexpr of the current buffer

```
:set indentexpr?
```

which returns,   `indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)`

and that `filetype plugin indent on` in your .vimrc is whats loading it when you load a python file

Comment: So the fix would be to increase the constant inside the script. It would be nice if this were a global config variable, so that this could be done from .vimrc; you may suggest that to the script author.

Comment: yup yup, one more thing though, I think generally you shouldn't expect indent scripts to work perfect when indenting the entire buffer gg=G,  it's more for indenting-while-you-edit.  Plus, the nested list in the example isn't really "normal" Python code  xD

Comment: Thanks David and Ingo.  This was a very specific case.  I totally understand that the code is far from "normal" python code.  This is one of the reasons why I'm currently reformatting the code.  The code is difficult enough for VIM to parse correctly, let alone read and comprehend with any speed.